# How to encrypt or encode the url in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encryption

I am using **ui.router** for routing in my web application.

Actually I have 5 pages to collect the information of client for account creation and I have used ui.router to navigate to those pages.

This is how the url looks like.

```
"www.mycompany.com/myproduct.html#/form/personal"
```

Now I want to prevent navigation to all the pages by typing the url directly in the address bar.

Is it possible that I can encrypt the url in such a way that one can't type the url in address bar to navigate to these pages. And is it possible to change the above url to the following ??

```
"www.mycompany.com/myproduct.html#/Zk3%dsUfdrt/Prtu883%$dddNC"
```

I have no Idea whether it is a valid question or not but all want to do is, not allowing someone to type the url and navigate and I want to prevent that using AngularJS.

Comment: send some token in the url then only allow a user to navigate. would it help.

Comment: @Jai , As per I know, we do that when we are making service call while loading the pages. But I am not making any service call in url.

And for service calls, I am using $http.get() or $http.post()

Comment: Try something at run phase.